# EF 6.0 Many to many relationship is not working in codefirst

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, ef-code-first, many-to-many

I have the following structure in database:

[image]

For the above I have the following in my C# code for EF 6.0 CodeFirst.

```
[Table("Person")]
public class User
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public long Id { get; set; }

    [Column("FullName")]
    [MaxLength(200)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Task> Tasks { get; set; } = new HashSet<Task>();
}



[Table("Task")]
public class Task
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public long Id { get; set; }

    [Column("FullName")]
    [MaxLength(200)]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<User> Users { get; set; } = new HashSet<User>();
}
```

The problem is that the collection is not getting populated at all and always returned as empty. for instance if I try:

```
userRepository.All.Include(x=>x.Tasks).Where(x=> x.FullName == "John").Select(x=> x.Tasks.Title).ToList();
```

> InnerException = {"Invalid object name 'dbo.PersonTask'."}

What is the problem with my code?

Comment: So is there a table called `dbo.PersonTask` in your database?  The error message suggests there is not, and your mapping may be off.

Comment: yes, it is but i dont have any mapping for it as it has no useful fields

Comment: Well SQL Server doesn't think you have such an object in your database.  Perhaps your connection string is wrong.

Comment: If you intend to use the Table PersonTask for the mapping table, create and apply a migration step. If you want to reuse an existing table with a different name, use the .HasMany().WithMany().Map(m=>m.ToTable()) function.

Comment: interesting. can't it pick all this info by itself? these tables already exist. we never build anything in database from code

Answer (score 0):

You don’t have the `PersonTask` table in database, so no entity is found in database. You have to create the mapping table.

Comment: i have  i even have data in it. in the database one one of my coworker has similar thing but he has mapping for intermediate table too and it works there. do you think i need an intermediate class too?

Comment: Yes you need it